# How to use the ground wire in 2 prong plugs

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

I bought a new monitor and it comes with a thick power plug but I noticed there's a ground wire dangling but sheathed with hard clear plastic but basically it looks like the image below:

[image]

What is the purpose of the ground wire? How should I use it? do I plug the wire in the grounding hole of the socket?

Comment: In Canada something like that would be illegal.  Used to be screwed on to screw holding outlet faceplate or an adapter.  Should be replaced with proper cord with three prong plug.  Was made illegal because most people would not use it and most times was a poor grounding connection.

Comment: Here they're still legal (as far as I know) because the alternative (folks yanking ground prongs out of their cords) is not ideal.

Comment: @isherwood sounds like a badly designed plug to me .... should use one more like the UK plug where even if you rip the cord out the plug, the earth is always the last to disconnect!

Comment: @UKMonkey Here we go again... you literally can't show a picture of an electrical plug anywhere without a Brit popping up to offer prayers for the BS 1363, lol.  Power strips the size of a lorry and munted feet from treading on those monsters... I don't miss them one bit. ;P

Comment: @J... They put lego to shame when it comes to feet killing - that's for sure!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That cord is meant to plug into a Japanese outlet.  In Japan, it's common to have two-prong sockets with a separate grounding screw below for devices that need it.

The outlet it was desinged to plug into looks something like this:

[image: Japanese outlet]

To use your monitor in the US, simply replace that cord with a standard US computer monitor cord, an IEC C13 - NEMA 5.  They're very inexpensive.

Comment: "Inexpensive" is right. I work at a computer service place, and we have so many of the things cluttering up our office that we'll just *give* you one if you stop by and ask nice.

Answer (score 8):

That type of wire, along with the tab on 3:2 "cheater plug" adapters, is intended to go under the face plate screw at the center of the outlet. That screw makes a connection with the outlet chassis, to which *its* grounding screw connects. Of course, this assumes that the outlet itself is grounded via wire or metal conduit.

[image]

[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Facworks.com%2Fblogs%2Fac-works-connector%2F2-3-prong-adapter-and-outlet-safety&psig=AOvVaw34dS0MHY4g1bv-9A74A0QQ&ust=1615044452684000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJDk7967me8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ)

Monitor cords are a dime a dozen. They're provided with a great many electrical appliances and folks tend to have extras laying around. If you prefer, swap that one out for a three-prong version.

Comment: is it safe to keep it dangling like that? it does have a kind of a plastic cap. not sure if I should tape it or not. Indeed 3 prong ones would be better.

Comment: Can also just cut that plug off and replace with proper three prong plug.

Comment: As cheap as proper 3-prong cords are, @crip659, it would be about the same to just buy a replacement cord and not have another hack job on site. (This plug contrivance being the first hack job.)

Comment: No danger in it dangling _other than the ungrounded state of your equipment_. Taping it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FreeMan  If monitor uses a standard/common plug that would be best, but it might use an odd plug to monitor and a replacement three prong plug for wall might be easier to get.  Not sure if cord OP shows is same as he has, said basically similar.  Think most of us in North America would find that cord hard to get.

Comment: @crip659 if it is that cord it would be incredibly easy to find pretty much anywhere in the world. It’s an IEC C13 cord. https://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?id=pcat17071&st=iec+cable